# Golang Concurrency Code Review of Codewalk

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

I'm trying to understand best practices for Golang concurrency. I read O'Reilly's book on Go's concurrency and then came back to the Golang Codewalks, specifically this example:

https://golang.org/doc/codewalk/sharemem/

This is the code I was hoping to review with you in order to learn a little bit more about Go. My first impression is that this code is breaking some best practices. This is of course my (very) unexperienced opinion and I wanted to discuss and gain some insight on the process. This isn't about who's right or wrong, please be nice, I just want to share my views and get some feedback on them. Maybe this discussion will help other people see why I'm wrong and teach them something.

I'm fully aware that the purpose of this code is to teach beginners, not to be perfect code.

**Issue 1 - No Goroutine cleanup logic**

```
func main() {
    // Create our input and output channels.
    pending, complete := make(chan *Resource), make(chan *Resource)

    // Launch the StateMonitor.
    status := StateMonitor(statusInterval)

    // Launch some Poller goroutines.
    for i := 0; i < numPollers; i++ {
        go Poller(pending, complete, status)
    }

    // Send some Resources to the pending queue.
    go func() {
        for _, url := range urls {
            pending <- &Resource{url: url}
        }
    }()

    for r := range complete {
        go r.Sleep(pending)
    }
}
```

The main method has no way to cleanup the Goroutines, which means if this was part of a library, they would be leaked.

**Issue 2 - Writers aren't spawning the channels**

I read that as a best practice, the logic to *create*, *write* and *cleanup* a channel should be controlled by a single entity (or group of entities). The reason behind this is that writers will panic when writing to a closed channel. So, it is best for the writer(s) to create the channel, write to it and control when it should be closed. If there are multiple writers, they can be synced with a WaitGroup.

```
func StateMonitor(updateInterval time.Duration) chan<- State {
    updates := make(chan State)
    urlStatus := make(map[string]string)
    ticker := time.NewTicker(updateInterval)
    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case <-ticker.C:
                logState(urlStatus)
            case s := <-updates:
                urlStatus[s.url] = s.status
            }
        }
    }()
    return updates
}
```

This function shouldn't be in charge of creating the updates channel because it is the reader of the channel, not the writer. The writer of this channel should create it and pass it to this function. Basically saying to the function "I will pass updates to you via this channel". But instead, this function is creating a channel and it isn't clear who is responsible of cleaning it up.

**Issue 3 - Writing to a channel asynchronously**

This function:

```
func (r *Resource) Sleep(done chan<- *Resource) {
    time.Sleep(pollInterval + errTimeout*time.Duration(r.errCount))
    done <- r
}
```

Is being referenced here:

```
for r := range complete {
    go r.Sleep(pending)
}
```

And it seems like an awful idea. When this channel is closed, we'll have a goroutine sleeping somewhere out of our reach waiting to write to that channel. Let's say this goroutine sleeps for 1h, when it wakes up, it will try to write to a channel that was closed in the cleanup process. This is another example of why the writters of the channels should be in charge of the cleanup process. Here we have a writer who's completely free and unaware of when the channel was closed.

**Please**

If I missed any issues from that code (related to concurrency), please list them. It doesn't have to be an objective issue, if you'd have designed the code in a different way for any reason, I'm also interested in learning about it.

**Biggest lesson from this code**

For me the biggest lesson I take from reviewing this code is that the cleanup of channels and the writing to them has to be synchronized. They have to be in the same for{} or at least communicate somehow (maybe via other channels or primitives) to avoid writing to a closed channel.

Comment: What is `Poller function` doing ? If this is a simple application in 1 file, can you update post with `GoPlayground` link?

Comment: @nipuna the question has a hyperlink with the source. https://golang.org/doc/codewalk/sharemem/ I'll edit the question to make it more visible

Comment: You may enjoy [Bryan Mills's GopherCon 2018 talk: Rethinking Classical Concurrency Patterns](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5zXAHh5tJqQ).

Comment: @jub0bs That video blew my mind. I never expected workerpool to be a bad practice! Do you have any other videos like that?

Comment: @AFP_555 Try this one: [Alan Shreve - Principles of designing Go APIs with channels (GopherCon India 2015)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hFqXgmor74k).

Comment: @AFP_555 And [Peter Bourgon - Ways To Do Things (Release Party #GoSF 2017)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LHe1Cb_Ud_M)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It *is* the `main` method, so there is no need to cleanup. When `main` returns, the program exits. If this wasn't the `main`, then you would be correct.
2. There is no best practice that fits all use cases. The code you show here is a very common pattern. The function creates a goroutine, and returns a channel so that others can communicate with that goroutine. There is no rule that governs how channels must be created. There is no way to terminate that goroutine though. One use case this pattern fits well is reading a large resultset from a
   database. The channel allows streaming data as it is read from the
   database. In that case usually there are other means of terminating the
   goroutine though, like passing a context.
3. Again, there are no hard rules on how channels should be created/closed. A channel can be left open, and it will be garbage collected when it is no longer used. If the use case demands so, the channel can be left open indefinitely, and the scenario you worry about will never happen.

Comment: But shouldn't we always strive to make the cleanup process of the goroutines we create?
Let's say today this logic is the main, but tomorrow I want to use it somewhere else. If I didn't think about the cleanup beforehand, it could mean drastically changing the design of the code just to make it reusable.

Comment: If you are dealing with resources that needs cleanup, then a graceful shutdown is necessary. If this code was not in main, it should've worried about the cleanup.

Comment: But it is a best practice to close them if they are no longer needed, right?

Comment: No, it is not. Closing a channel is usually used to communicate the end of a data stream. You don't have to close channels. To put it another way: closing a channel does not free up resources. The channel still sits there with a flag saying it is closed.

Comment: Closing a channel is also the only way to broadcast some information to all goroutines listening to that channel.

Comment: Wow, I had no idea closing a channel didn't cleanup resources. That's good to know. So the only way to clean those resources is when we no longer have references to it and the GC cleans it, regardless of the channel state (open, closed).

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8593645/is-it-ok-to-leave-a-channel-open/8593986

Answer (score 2):

1. As you are asking about if this code was part of a library, yes it would be poor practice to spawn goroutines with no cleanup inside a library function. If those goroutines carry out documented behaviour of the library, it's problematic that the caller *doesn't know when that behaviour is going to happen*. If you have any behaviour that is typically "fire and forget", it should be the caller who chooses when to forget about it. For example:

```golang
func doAfter5Minutes(f func()) {
   go func() {
       time.Sleep(5 * time.Minute)
       f()
       log.Println("done!")
   }()
}
```

Makes sense, right? When you call the function, it does something 5 minutes later. The problem is that it's easy to misuse this function like this:

```golang
// do the important task every 5 minutes
for {
    doAfter5Minutes(importantTaskFunction)
}
```

At first glance, this might seem fine. We're doing the important task every 5 minutes, right? In reality, we're spawning many goroutines very quickly, probably consuming all available memory before they start dropping off.

We could implement some kind of callback or channel to signal when the task is done, but really, the function should be simplified like so:

```golang
func doAfter5Minutes(f func()) {
   time.Sleep(5 * time.Minute)
   f()
   log.Println("done!")
}
```

Now the caller has the choice of how to use it:

```golang
// call synchronously
doAfter5Minutes(importantTaskFunction)
// fire and forget
go doAfter5Minutes(importantTaskFunction)
```

2. This function arguably should also be changed. As you say, the writer should effectively own the channel, as they should be the one closing it. The fact that this channel-reading function insists on creating the channel it reads from actually coerces itself into this poor "fire and forget" pattern mentioned above. Notice how the function needs to read from the channel, but it also needs to return the channel before reading. It therefore had to put the reading behaviour in a new, un-managed goroutine to allow itself to return the channel right away.

```golang
func StateMonitor(updates chan State, updateInterval time.Duration) {
    urlStatus := make(map[string]string)
    ticker := time.NewTicker(updateInterval)
    defer ticker.Stop() // not stopping the ticker is also a resource leak

    for {
        select {
        case <-ticker.C:
            logState(urlStatus)
        case s := <-updates:
            urlStatus[s.url] = s.status
        }
    }

}
```

Notice that the function is now simpler, more flexible and synchronous. The only thing that the previous version really accomplishes, is that it (mostly) guarantees that each instance of `StateMonitor` will have a channel all to itself, and you won't have a situation where multiple monitors are competing for reads on the same channel. While this *may* help you avoid a certain class of bugs, it also makes the function a lot less flexible and more likely to have resource leaks.

3. I'm not sure I really understand this example, but the golden rule for channel closing is that the writer should always be responsible for closing the channel. Keep this rule in mind, and notice a few points about this code:

- The `Sleep` method writes to `r`
- The `Sleep` method is executed concurrently, with no method of tracking how many instances are running, what state they are in, etc.

Based on these points alone, we can say that there probably isn't *anywhere* in the program where it would be safe to close `r`, because there's seemingly no way of knowing if it will be used again.